# Why doesn't my log info contain the debugging source place?

Tags: python

```
2019-06-21 07:48:16 INFO     root  - Slot date:'None'
2019-06-21 07:48:16 INFO     root  - Slot location: '大津市'
2019-06-21 07:48:16 INFO     root  - Mapped location:'Ōtsu'
2019-06-21 07:48:16 INFO     root  - Place and date: Ōtsu None
2019-06-21 07:48:16 INFO     root  - Place queried at get_forecaster_at_place:Ōtsu
```

The way I am using the logging:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

 ...
 logging.info("...")
```

It only shows the 'root', without showing which class or library it comes from, which is bad.

How to make it show the logging source place too?

Comment: You are logging from different python files? You should add at the beginning of each file `logger = logging.getLogger("module_name")` and then use `logger.info(...)`. Have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-logging-in-multiple-modules)

Comment: @Tomerikoo That works and thanks. But why when I change 'info' to 'debug', the debugging info doesn't print out to the console? I want to see debug info.

Comment: `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)`..... choose your level between DEBUG, INFO, WARNING and ERROR. again, you should research a bit more before asking here. have a deeper read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#module-logging)